Trying to return a found item from an actors inventory within foundry vtt
Hi i am trying to create a macro in foundry that looks for a health potion within an selected actor's inventory, if its found i will do something to expend it as a use, if not found then return an error to foundry. The code i have below is how far i have got but it's returning the error despite the item being in the actor's inventory.
Can anyone point me in the correct direction?


main()

async function main() {

// Is a token selected? If not, error
    console.log("Tokens: ", canvas.tokens.controlled)
    if(canvas.tokens.controlled.length == 0 || canvas.tokens.controlled.length > 1){
        ui.notifications.error("Please select a single token")
        return;
    }
    let actor = canvas.tokens.controlled[0].actor
    console.log(actor)
// Does the token have a health potion?
    let healthpotion = actor.items.find(item => item.value == "Potion of Greater Healing")
console.log(healthpotion)
    if(healthpotion == null || healthpotion == undefined){
        ui.notifications.error("No Health Potions left");
        return;
    }



From the console i can see the potion in the array but my code isn't finding it.


on javascript, I suggest to always use  "===" when doing comparisons

Thanks ooshp,
I have the answer, i needed to drop the .value and just have item.name, spent hours on this

I haven't used Foundry in a long time, but it looks like you want this part:
let healthpotion = actor.items.find(item => item.value == "Potion of Greater Healing")

to be this:
let healthpotion = actor.items.find(item => item.value.name == "Potion of Greater Healing")

Also keep in mind you can log inside a loop if you're not familiar with what you're iterating through, to make debugging easier:
let healthpotion = actor.items.find(item => {
    console.log(item);
    return item.value.name == "Potion of Greater Healing";
});


Doesn't seem to like the .name after value, but taking that out and running the iteration i get:
Item5e {name: 'Potion of Greater Healing', type: 'consumable', img: 'https://assets.forge-vtt.com/bazaar/core/icons/con…ables/potions/bottle-bulb-corked-glowing-red.webp', system: ConsumableData, #validationFailures: {…}, …}
So how do i get it to grab the name bit from this?
